# Is it possible to see when a bluetooth device was last connected?

Tags: bluetooth

I misplaced my bluetooth headphones, does anyone know whether it is possible to get a history when they were last connected on my Android 11 google Pixel 3A? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably not. There for sure is no such log on my own iPhone for my Bluetooth ear pieces.